Parallelism in AWS Glue
I am reading a large file from S3 in a Glue job. Its a .txt file which I convert to .csv and read all the values in a particular column.
I want to leverage parallelism of Glue over here where the reading part can be taken as a task by glue workers.
Do I need to programmatically split the file and then submit the small chunks to the workers or does Spark take care of the parallelism by itself and is smart enough to split the file by itself and distribute it to the workers?

AWS Glue by itself splits file and distributes to worker nodes, as it uses Spark, so no manual splitting of file is required. However, you can leverage parallelism properties of Spark,

spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes: The maximum number of bytes to
pack into a single partition when reading files. Default is 128 MB.

spark.sql.files.minPartitionNum: The suggested (not guaranteed)
minimum number of partitions when reading files. Default is
spark.default.parallelism which equals to two or the total number of
cores in our cluster, whichever is bigger.


You can refer more in these pages: Salesforce Engineering Blog
Apache Spark Doc

Thanks. So in the glue job, I receive the bucket name in the input event to the glue job. I then read the file inside the bucket using s3 client. Do you mean once I start the processing of the file by reading the contents of the file, spark automatically divides this processing to multiple workers?

Yes, Spark by design does the processing by distribution

Ok. So is there a need to convert the.txt file to.csv or will the file be split irrespective of the format of the file? I presume in case of txt file size based splitting will be done?

it will be done irrespective of format, based file format type execution time change. Here both txt and csv are text based file types, so there will be negligible impact
